# ActiveMQ: Configure secured LDAPS connection to AD

Tags: ssl, active-directory, ldap, connection, activemq-classic

I am using ActiveMQ 5.16.2 and try to secure the ActiveMQ Web console with LDAP. I have followed [this guide](https://workhorseintegrations.com/2020/05/14/securing-activemq-console-with-ldap/).

Because I am not that familiar with LDAP I used `ldapsearch` from openldap-clients to perform some initial queries to check if my `roleFilter` and `userFilter` within `LdapRoleAuthorizationModule` have the correct settings.

When using `ldapsearch` I have received the following error:

```
ldap_bind: Strong(er) authentication required (8)
Ldap_bind: additional info:00002028:ldapERR:DSID-0C09027F,comment: The server requires binds to turn on the integrity checking if SSL/TLS are not already active on the connection, data 0, v3839
```

I tried to search how I can configure a secured `ldaps` connection from my ActiveMQ VM to solve this error but was not able to find a good solution.

Could someone give advice / help please?

Comment: So did you get that error when using `ldapsearch` or ActiveMQ? The configuration for `ldapsearch` is going to be quite different from ActiveMQ.

Comment: Also, for an LDAP connection which uses SSL from ActiveMQ why can you just use `ldaps://<host>:<port>`?

Comment: Hi ldaps is working now.

Comment: How did you get it to work?